# How can I adjust the recursion depth at which the "Deep recursion on subroutine" warning is emitted?

Tags: perl, recursion, warnings

In [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20710284/133939) the OP alluded to the feasibility of adjusting the recursion depth from the default setting of 100.

> There *are* ways to extend this limit or to turn it off entirely...

The [`warnings`](https://metacpan.org/pod/warnings) documentation doesn't seem to say anything about how this can be achieved.

Is there a way to raise the limit without turning the warning off or resorting to some hackish `$stack_level` variable?

Answer (score 2):

With debugger: `$DB::deep = 500;`
Without debugger: I only saw reference suggesting to recompile perl binary with different `PERL_SUB_DEPTH_WARN` macro

Answer (score 0):

```
# disable 'Deep recursion on subroutine ...' warnings completely
no warnings 'recursion';
```